# Convert Task ActivityDate into String

Tags: tasks, string, convert, format

I need in my wrapper class the activity date from the task object as string to display at a visual force page. My two version below does n't work.

**If I use this version I get an error (Attempt to de-reference a null object).**

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    
    private final Id id;
    private final DateTime createDateSort;
    private final String createDate;
       
    public wrapper(Task t) { 
        id                    = t.Id;
        DateTime activitydate = t.ActivityDate;
        createDate            = activitydate.format('dd.MM.yy', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
        createDateSort        = t.ActivityDate;           
    }
```

**And if I use this version I get the error (Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void format(String) from the type Date**

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    
    private final Id id;
    private final DateTime createDateSort;
    private final String createDate;
       
    public wrapper(Task t) { 
        id                  = t.Id;
        createDate          = t.activitydate.format('dd.MM.yy');
        createDateSort      = t.ActivityDate;           
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because there were tasks with no activitydate. I add an If-Clause to solve the problem.

```
    If (t.ActivityDate == Null) { 
        createDateSort  = t.CreatedDate;
        createDate      = t.CreatedDate.format('dd.MM.yy', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
    } ELSE {
        DateTime ActivityDate = t.ActivityDate;
        createDateSort        = t.ActivityDate;
        createDate            = ActivityDate.format('dd.MM.yy', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
createDate = string.valueOfGmt(createDateSort);
```